# is insert based on select on one of the column in MySQL possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is following insert based on select on one of the column possible in MySQL

```
INSERT INTO student_fees(id, name, fees) 
VALUES(1, SELECT name from students where student_id = 1, 200$)
```

If yes then and example will really help.

-Thanks

Comment: The [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) states clearly that it is possible. However your syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `INSERT...SELECT` statement

```
INSERT INTO student_fees(id, name, fees) 
SELECT ... -- put here the SELECT STATEMENT with condition
```

if your column `ID` is `auto incremented`, you don't have to specify the `1` or else it will cause you an error.

```
INSERT INTO student_fees(name, fees) 
SELECT `name`, '200$' 
FROM students         -- this will select all students on the table
                      -- and add $200 on thier fees.
```

Another point is, if you only want to insert one column from the `student`'s table, you need yo specify the condition, so you will not get constraint error (*assuming your column ID is the Primary Key*)

```
INSERT INTO student_fees(name, fees) 
SELECT `name`, '200$' 
FROM   students
WHERE  columnName = 'blahBlah'
```

**UPDATE 1**

Seeing your comment, you have this query

```
INSERT INTO coupon_allotment (page_id, offer_id, coupon_code, user_id) 
SELECT page_id, 4, 'ABC'        -- number of columns mismatch, right?
FROM pages_discounts_association 
WHERE discount_id = 4
```

you need **to remove** the `user_id` column above OR you need **to add** an `ID` in your select statement in order to match the number of columns.

Comment: INSERT INTO coupon_allotment(page_id, offer_id, coupon_code, user_id) SELECT page_id, 4, 'ABC' FROM pages_discounts_association WHERE discount_id = 4      This is my actual query can you correct this for me?

Comment: it's a number of column mismatch. i just updated my query.. see if it works now.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the regular `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax and select the other fields as constants as follows:

```
INSERT INTO student_fees(id, name, fees) 
SELECT 1, `name`, '200$' FROM students
```

Comment: doesnt work following is the actual query: INSERT INTO `coupon_allotment`(page_id, offer_id, coupon_code, user_id) SELECT page_id, 4, 'ABC' FROM `pages_discounts_association` WHERE `discount_id` = 4

Comment: @Abhishek Your table in the actual query has 4 columns (page_id, offer_id, coupon_code, user_id), while in the `SELECT` you just have 3. You have to have as many columns in the `SELECT` as you have in the `INSERT` statement for this query to work!

Comment: @Abhishek: you must have the same number of fields in `VALUES(...)` and in `SELECT`. In your case: 4 fields then 3 fields.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO student_fees(id, name, fees) 
Select 1, name,'200$' from students
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also capture 1 field from another table and insert other data from another source or variables.

```
INSERT INTO student_fees(id, name, fees) VALUES 
((SELECT id FROM table_2 WHERE name = 'John' LIMIT 1), 'nameValue', 'fees');
```